# Apache Spark: Calling setCallSite(description) when a stage really starts, not during the analysis phase

Tags: java, apache-spark

`setJobDescription(description)` allows to put a name to a job (the action) we are doing.
Often, for a *Spark* session, a single call is enough for me : a `collect()`, a `show()`, and I'm done.

But for stages, it's different. A the time *Spark* plan to do a transformation somewhat "moving" it creates one. `filter(...)`, `map(...)`, `groupBy(...)`...
I would like to put also stages names with `setCallSite(description)`.

But there's a trap. Here's my job :

```java
session.setJobDescription("accounting balance")

// Many transformations that are creating stages
// ---------------------------------------------
session.sparkContext().setCallSite("Reading account data for cities");
Dataset<Row> comptes = load(/* ...stage : load from store... */)

session.sparkContext().setCallSite("Checking validity of records");
comptes = comptes.filter((FilterFunction<Row>)compte -> {
   /* stage : checking validity of records */
});
      
session.sparkContext().setCallSite("Adding account descriptions from nomenclatures");
comptes = comptes.join( /*... stage : adding account descriptions from accounting plan */)
      
session.sparkContext().setCallSite("Confrontation with city code"));
comptes = comptes.join(/*....stage joining geographical code ...*/)
comptes = comptes.filter(/*....stage : removing unknown cities ...*/)
      
session.sparkContext().setCallSite("Cumulation of root accounts");
comptes = /* many stages behind : it's a method */
      
// Job done.
comptes.show(); // the action
```

Here's what I see on Spark UI, all the time :

```
Accounting balance
   Cumulation of root accounts
```

It's normal : *Spark* generated its plan, its DAG, by going over my code a first time, during the analysis phase.
And it **executed all** the `session.sparkContext().setCallSite(...)` it contains, until the last one.
This, **before having started any stage**.

If I was really willing the stage name to be displayed at due time, theoretically, I should have to write something like that, instead :

```java
comptes = comptes.filter((FilterFunction<Row>)compte -> {
   session.sparkContext().setCallSite("Checking validity of records");
   /* stage : checking validity of records */
});
```

But it's not possible, and more : it would be very dirty. Setting the same description at each iteration of the filter loop !!!

What's the way to change the call site description at the very time a stage is starting, and not during the analysis phase ?